# Fill SVG Animation with Tailwind on Hover

Tags: css-animations, tailwind-css

I am really stuck with this one, I am trying to achieve this result for days now, I searched all over google for answers but had no luck.
This is the result I want to achieve:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgU0t.gif]

I am building it with tailwind like this:

```html
<section class="bg-black justify-center text-center items-center">

 <a href="#" class="flex items-center justify-center text-center z-100 pointer-events-auto w-1/2 group">

   <svg class=" translate-x-full transition-all duration-200 w-full h-full opacity-25 overflow-hidden" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 61 41" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"><title>Arrow Right Large Icon</title><path d="M39.813 37.806l15.312-17.018L39.813 3.775M56.5 20.787H.5" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="8"></path></svg>
    <div class="-translate-x-full block transition-all duration-200 w-full h-full overflow-hidden">
      <svg class="z-100  group-hover:translate-x-full transition-all duration-200 w-full h-full overflow-hidden " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 61 41" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"><title>Arrow Right Large Icon</title><path d="M39.813 37.806l15.312-17.018L39.813 3.775M56.5 20.787H.5" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="8"></path></svg>
    </div>
 
 </a>
 </div>
 </section>
```

I use https://play.tailwindcss.com/ to test it.